# Regex: how to identify words in a screen (or how to exclude punctuation and numbers)

Tags: python, regex, words

Can someone help me with identifying words only in the text file? Upper or lower case but no numbers, brackets, dashes, punctuation, etc.(whatever the definition of the "word" is)

I was thinking about:

```
r"\w+ \w+"
```

but it does not work

Thank you

Comment: `[a-z]+ [A-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+`. Of course this is not unicode aware

Answer (score 1):

You can use a character class with specifying the range of expected characters :

```
r'[a-zA-Z]+'
```

Read more here http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

And in python you can use the function `re.findall()` to return all the matches in a list or `re.finditer` which returns an iterator of match objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall(r"\b[a-z]+\b",test_str,re.I)
```

You can do it this way.

Comment: not exactly. for "I love. 5 lucy," the out out is ['l', 'o', 'v', 'e', 'l', 'u', 'c', 'y']  just gives all right letters but separately. can this be adjusted to give a word?

Comment: Output - ['love', 'lucy']. Perfect but I guess it can not consider "I" as a word

Comment: @Toly `I` will be there in output

Comment: sorry, but it is not there

Comment: wordID = r"\b[a-z]+\b"
    wordI = re.compile(wordID, re.VERBOSE)

    wordCL = wordI.findall("I, love. 5: lucy,!",re.IGNORECASE)

Comment: but Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
text = "hey there 222 how are you ??? fine I hope!"
print re.findall("[a-z]+", subject, re.IGNORECASE)
#['hey', 'there', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'fine', 'I', 'hope']
```

---

Regex explanation

```
[a-z]+

Options: Case insensitive;

Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” «[a-z]+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```

---

**Python Live Demo**

http://ideone.com/JT8ZjD